# Cordova OverrideUserAgent preference not working

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, quasar-framework

I'm building hybrid mobile apps using cordova and quasar framework.

I used the following user agent to change the default user agent.

```
<preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 Google" />
```

in config.xml for both ios and android preferences

its working fine for iOS but
not working for android (giving null value in OverrideUserAgent preference in generated code)

cordova-lib@9.0.1

platforms list :

android@8.1.0 and ios@4.5.5

How do i make it work for android ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `AppendUserAgent` instead?

> If set, the value will replace the old UserAgent of webview. It is
> helpful to identify the request from app/browser when requesting
> remote pages. Use with caution, this may causes compitiable issue with
> web servers. For most cases, use AppendUserAgent instead.

Comment: I suppose at this stage you'd better open a bug report to cordova